# MySQL: Does querying for value that doesn't exist in index (even if colunn IS indexed) cause full table scan?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a indexed datetime value. Let's say its called event_datetime.

If I query using known existing values in table, the query is faster than if I use an arbitrary bound eg.:

```
SELECT SUM(event_datetime) FROM table WHERE DATE(event_datetime) >= '2020-03-01' AND DATE(event_datetime) <= '2020-03-21';
```

versus:

```
SELECT SUM(event_datetime) FROM table WHERE DATE(event_datetime) >= '2020-03-01' AND DATE(event_datetime) <= '2020-03-31';
```

Assuming data only rows with event_datetime up to and including '2020-03-21' exist in table, does the latter statement querying for up to 31st cause a full table scan since the values larger than '2020-03-21' are not found in the idnex?

Comment: a) I don't see any difference between the two queries. (b) An index on `event_datetime` cannot be used as you apply a function (`date()`) on it. You should use a range expression to fix that, like `event_datetime >= '2020-03-01' AND event_datetime < '2020-04-01'`. (c) What is the `sum()` of a `datetime` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, the problem with your query is that you are using date functions on predicates:

> `DATE(event_datetime) >= '2020-03-01' AND DATE(event_datetime) <= '2020-03-21'`

Using `DATE()` on the column being filtered actually prevents the database from taking advantage of an index on `event_datetime`, because the function must be applied to all the values in the column before the filtering occurs. We say it makes the query non SARGeable.

A much better option is to do:

```
event_datetime >= '2020-03-01' AND event_datetime < '2020-03-21'
```